# Snowflake date shifted by 1 day when importing the data into R

Tags: sql, r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a database in SNOWFLAKE. When I execute this query

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID, DUE_DATE FROM table WHERE REQUEST_ID = 'abc'
```

I get this as result.

[image]

I execute the same query in R

```
query <- "SELECT REQUEST_ID, DUE_DATE FROM table WHERE REQUEST_ID = 'abc'"
data1 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

I get this as result.

[image]

As you may have noticed the dates are shifted by 1 day. The data type in snowflake is of type DATE whereas in R it is of type character. I am not sure what is causing this issue. I initially thought it might be because of timezone so I tried changing timezone in SNOWFLAKE by running the following lines

```
ALTER USER SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

but it did not change anything. Later I read that DATES do not have time component in them so are not affected by timezones. I am not sure where to look and what to change to fix this issue. I would appreciate if you could give me any pointers.

This is how I create the connection (`con`) object -

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RJDBC::JDBC("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver", driver), url)
```

Comment: How is the connection done? Using ODBC driver or the OOTB Snowflake driver which is provided with the latest RStudio installation? Can you post the connection UI screenshot for checking the details?

Comment: @SrinathMenon It is an internal package which does the connection but I think this is the main line in it. `con <- DBI::dbConnect(RJDBC::JDBC("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver", driver), url)` where `driver`  is the path and url is the database server url.

Comment: What version of JDBC is used there? There were some issues in the past versions with DATE objects. Can you also check if [JDBC_USE_SESSION_TIMEZONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#jdbc-use-session-timezone) has been changed?

Comment: Sorry @Sergiu , I am not aware how do I check both of this. Can you help me with the command/steps to check it ? Thank you for helping.

Comment: For the parameter you can do this on Snowflake UI: **show parameters like 'JDBC_USE_SESSION_TIMEZONE';**, for the JDBC version I assume you have the **jar** file stored somewhere (I am not familiar with R). The jar filename contains the version as well (something like this **snowflake-jdbc-3.13.9.jar**)

Comment: @Sergiu  For parameters I get `value = true` and `description` as `When true, JDBC driver will not display timezone offset between JVM and session.` Do you need something else ? Jar file name is `snowflake-jdbc.jar`. Maybe the file was renamed as it does not have the version number. Is there some other way to get the version number ?

Comment: When true it means JDBC will use whatever timezone is set on the Session (specified by TIMEZONE parameter, UTC on your case). As for JDBC version, it should be in the [driver log](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) if generated.

Comment: On a side note, can you test this with the default snowflake driver provided and see if the same behavior is seen as in the date display 1 day shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a bug in the previous version of the driver and updating the driver to latest version fixes the issue.

This one is a related issue here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/pull/434 and you can install the latest version of the driver from here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/

Note that the version number is not sorted numerically on that page.